# PHPMyAdmin - Deleting rows from table with no unique column

Tags: wordpress

This is really annoying, I've encountered this problem plenty of times when importing a database:
https://i.gyazo.com/8051625ceaa6f2e00212a134a96a485e.png

Because it has no unique column, I can't delete rows. Because I can't delete rows, I can't assign a unique column because I can't delete the rows with duplicate entries for that column (those rows with ID = 0).

I can't remember how I fixed this before. I have no idea how this problem even happens, I thought the wp_options table would have a unique key on the ID column by default.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, sorry the solution was really simple. PHPMyAdmin just prevents you from deleting rows through the GUI, but the SQL query to delete the rows still works. I deleted those duplicate rows by going into the SQL tab and running `DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = '0';`

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this problem, and thought the same thing (NOTE: It's NOT just the wp_options table - you're going to have issues on other tables as well!)

The issue is the way the export / import is processed.

There's a subtle "autoincrement" checkbox somewhere in the phpMyAdmin interface for the export under the "object creation" options:

[image: phpMyAdmin Export Options]

NOTE: Once you've exported / imported, and find yourself dealing with this, the simplest way that I've come up with to solve the issue is:

1. Create a new column titled 'new_ID', make it `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
2. Then, 
   a. either run a query to update the existing ID column to the new_ID value, OR
   b. Delete the existing ID column, and rename 'new_ID' to the correct name, and add a `PRIMARY KEY` index.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what caused the problem. When importing the SQL file, there was an error when importing one of the keys for one of the tables. As a result, it skipped the importing of every key after that, and the option_id unique key was one of the keys it skipped. So yeah you were right, the problem happened with a lot of other tables too. The solution was to import the rest of the keys and indexes and stuff from the .sql file.

What I mean is this:

--

### -- Indexes for table `wp_links`

ALTER TABLE `wp_links`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`link_id`), ADD KEY `link_visible` (`link_visible`);

--

### -- Indexes for table `wp_options`

ALTER TABLE `wp_options`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `option_name` (`option_name`), ADD KEY `wpe_autoload_options_index` (`autoload`);

I forgot to delete the wp_links table before importing the new database tables, so it couldn't create the link_id primary key since it already existed. As a result, every key that appeared in the file after that one got skipped.